# How to efficiently segment NumPy array by creating separate binary arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-segmentation

I'm trying to separate distinct objects in an image stored in the form of a NumPy array. For instance, if I have the 2D NumPy array:

```py
X = np.array([[1.4E14, 1.4E14, 1.6E14], [1.4E14, 1.6E14, 1.6E14], [1.6E14, 1.1E14, 1.1E14]])
```

How can I separate this into binary arrays of the same shape by instance like this:

```py
Y = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]])
Z = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]])
W = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]])
```

Where `Y` represents values of `1.4E14`, `Z` represents values of `1.6E14`, and `W` represents values of `1.1E14`, and all instances are the same shape as the original array. Any ideas on how to do this efficiently for large array sizes?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np

X = ([1.4E14, 1.4E14, 1.6E14], [1.4E14, 1.6E14, 1.6E14], [1.6E14, 1.1E14, 1.1E14])

numbers = [1.4E14, 1.6E14, 1.1E14]

x = np.array(X)

for j in numbers:
    result = (x == j)+0
    print("comparing with " + str(j))
    print(result[:].tolist())
    print("")
```

Comment: for loops are not efficient

Answer (score 0):

You want [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
values = {1.4E14, 1.6E14, 1.1E14}

lst = []
for k, v in values.items():
    lst.append(np.where(X == val, 1, 0))
```

The one liner
`{k: (X == v).astype(np.int) for k, v in {'Y': 14, 'Z': 16, 'W': 11}.items()}`

```
{
'Y': array([[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]), 
'Z': array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]]), 
'W': array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumPy's [`unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) function to find the unique values in `X`, [`equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html) to compare `X` element-wise to those values and [`astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) method to cast the result to integer:

```py
In [76]: import numpy as np

In [77]: X = np.array([[1.4E14, 1.4E14, 1.6E14], 
    ...:               [1.4E14, 1.6E14, 1.6E14], 
    ...:               [1.6E14, 1.1E14, 1.1E14]])
    ...: 

In [78]: for value in np.unique(X):
    ...:     binary_array = np.equal(X, value).astype(int)
    ...:     print(f'{value:.1E}\n{binary_array}\n')
    ...: 
    ...: 
1.1E+14
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 1 1]]

1.4E+14
[[1 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]

1.6E+14
[[0 0 1]
 [0 1 1]
 [1 0 0]]
```

In the code above `binary_array = np.int_(X == value)` would also work.